# How to randomly generate an unobserved data in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random, sampling

I have an dataframe which contain the observed data as:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'humanID': [1, 1, 2,2,2,2 ,2,2,2,2], 'dogID': 
[1,2,1,5,4,6,7,20,9,7],'month': [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The `df` is follow

```
    humanID  dogID  month
0        1      1      1
1        1      2      1
2        2      1      2
3        2      5      3
4        2      4      1
5        2      6      2
6        2      7      3
7        2     20      1
8        2      9      2
9        2      7      2
```

We total have two `human` and twenty `dog`, and above `df` contains the observed data. For example:

The first row means: `human1` adopt `dog1` at January

The second row means: `human1` adopt `dog2` at January

The third row means: `human2` adopt `dog1` at Febuary

========================================================================

My goal is randomly generating `two` unobserved data for each `(human, month)` that are not appear in the original observed data.

like for `human1` at `January`, he does't adopt the dog `[3,4,5,6,7,..20]` And I want to randomly create two unobserved sample `(human, month)` in triple form

```
humanID dogID month
   1      20    1
   1      10    1
```

However, the follow sample is not allowed since it appear in original `df`

```
  humanID dogID month
   1        2    1
```

For `human1`, he doesn't have any activity at Feb, so we don't need to sample the unobserved data.

For `human2`, he have activity for Jan, Feb and March. Therefore, for each month, we want to randomly create the unobserved data. For example, In Jan, `human2` adopt `dog1`, `dog4` and `god 20`. The two random unobserved samples can be

```
humanID dogID month
   2      2    1
   2      6    1
```

same process can be used for Feb and March.

I want to put all of the unobserved in one dataframe such as follow `unobserved`

```
    humanID  dogID  month
0        1      20      1
1        1      10      1
2        2      2       1
3        2      6       1
4        2      13      2
5        2      16      2
6        2      1       3
7        2      20      3
```

Any fast way to do this?

PS: this is a code interview for a start-up company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `random.choices`:

```
import random

dogs = list(range(1,21))
dfs = []
n_sample = 2
for i,d in df.groupby(['humanID', 'month']):
    h_id, month = i
    sample = pd.DataFrame([(h_id, dogID, month) for dogID in random.choices(list(set(dogs)-set(d['dogID'])), k=n_sample)])
    dfs.append(sample)
new_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.columns = ['humanID', 'dogID', 'month']

print(new_df)
   humanID  dogID  month
0        1     11      1
1        1      5      1
2        2     19      1
3        2     18      1
4        2     15      2
5        2     14      2
6        2     16      3
7        2     18      3
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`np.random.permutation()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) for the `dogID` column to generate random permutations of the column,

```
df_new=df.copy()
df_new['dogID']=np.random.permutation(df.dogID)
print(df_new.sort_values('month'))

   humanID  dogID  month
0        1      1      1
1        1     20      1
4        2      9      1
7        2      1      1
2        2      4      2
5        2      5      2
8        2      2      2
9        2      7      2
3        2      7      3
6        2      6      3
```

*Or to create random sampling of missing values within the range of dogID:*

```
df_new=df.copy()
a=np.random.permutation(range(df_new.dogID.min(),df_new.dogID.max()))
df_new['dogID']=np.random.choice(a,df_new.shape[0])
print(df_new.sort_values('month'))

   humanID  dogID  month
0        1     18      1
1        1     16      1
4        2      1      1
7        2      8      1
2        2      4      2
5        2      2      2
8        2     16      2
9        2     14      2
3        2      4      3
6        2     12      3
```

Comment: That's a good point, Do you know how to fix the number of unobserved data? for example, we only need `two` unobserved samples for each pair of `(humanID, dogID)`.

Comment: @jason i meant the groupby should be on the final output `df_new`

Comment: I try your code. It seems that the `df_new` sometimes contain the observed row in original `df`. How to make sure those unobserved data will not appear the row in   `df`? Thanks

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The problem now is more clear. the intersection of `df_new` and `df` should be `null`. I am still thinking how to achieve based on your code